# Converting virtual drives from .vmdk to .vhdx produces huge files

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, vmware-vmdk, vmdk, vhdx

I'm using powershell and ConvertTo-MvmcVirtualHardDisk cmdlet to convert .vmdk disks into .vhdx disks to be able to run them in our hyper-v environment. For some reason, the .vhdx files produced are huge, sometimes as much as ten times the original file size. Does anyone know why this is?

The source files are, for the record, from one of our clients so I don't really know how they were set up.

Thanks!

Comment: A guess about the "why": thin vs thick provisioned disks.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue, I always use [Disk2VHD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd) now, I have tried many different methods but always end up back with this simple tool. It works brilliantly every time.